# Woocommerce create_category hook not working for product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I want to hook into *create_category* and *edit_category* for products in WooCommerce. However it seems like it’s not using these hooks when creating / editing categories?

I know the hooks work for standard categories for stuff like blog posts.

It seems weird because for products itself I can just use the standard hooks for posts like *transition_post_status* and *delete_post* etc.

Does it use a different hook for product categories specific or does it not at all? Is there a way to do this?

Here’s just a little code I used to try the hook out:

```
add_action('create_category', 'sync_product_category', 10, 1);
function sync_product_category( $catid ) {
    $category = get_category($catid);
    error_log('category created');
}
```

it logs to the `error_log.log` fine when I create a category from blog posts, but when I create one in WooCommerce, it doesn’t show up.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it resolved.

Comment: Wow, 2 years later and that comment worked! Thanks very much.

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hook into woocommerce product category creation use this line:

```
add_action('create_product_cat', 'sync_product_category', 10, 1);
```

The action you want to hook into is `do_action( "create_$taxonomy", $term_id, $tt_id );` in the function `wp_insert_term` in `wp-includes/taxonomy.php`. The value of `$taxonomy` in your case is 'product_cat'.